# Expando Object and IEnumerable returns cannot convert implicitly void to object

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, expandoobject

This code is throwing and error 'cannot implicitly convert type void to object'

```
dynamic disruption1 = new ExpandoObject();
disruption1.locationsAffected = new string[] { "london", "panama" };
IEnumerable<dynamic> disruptionList = new List<dynamic>().Add(disruption1);
```

But I am not sure what is wrong, I also tried

```
dynamic disruptionList = new List<dynamic>().Add(disruption1);
```

and it doesn't throw the error but is not what I need.

I am creating a unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `Add()` method is `void` and you are trying to assign `void` to variable of type `List<dynamic>` which is absolutely not allowed and compiler will throw error which you are seeing,as you already have reference to the `List<T>`, add the item on the new line following way:

```
dynamic disruptionList = new List<dynamic>();
disruptionList.Add(disruption1);
```

Comment: wao, I totally missed that! fool of me, thank you very much. I think I am just tired.